# how to load classes from a jar file and store it in an arraylist

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to load the class files(which do not implement any common interface) from the exchanges.jar file and store it in an arraylist
Previously, i loaded the .class files(which implements a common interface) from a directory using

```
package edu.uh.cs.assign2;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import edu.uh.cs.iexchangeservices.IExchange;

public class ExchangeManager {
    private ArrayList<IExchange> exchangeList = new ArrayList<IExchange>();

    public ArrayList<IExchange> findClasses() throws Exception {

        File classDirectoryPath = new File(Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource("exchangeservices".replace('.', '/')).getFile());

        return loadExchangeClasses(classDirectoryPath);
    }

    public ArrayList<IExchange> loadExchangeClasses(File classDirectoryPath)
            throws Exception {

        if (!classDirectoryPath.exists())
            throw new LoadExchangesException("path not found");

        String[] exchangeClasses = classDirectoryPath.list();

        for (String exchangeClass : exchangeClasses) {

            if (exchangeClass.endsWith(".class")) {
                Object object = (IExchange) Class.forName(
                        "exchangeservices"
                                + '.'
                                + exchangeClass.substring(0,
                                        exchangeClass.length() - 6))
                        .newInstance();

                if (object instanceof IExchange)
                    exchangeList.add((IExchange) object);
            }
        }
        return exchangeList;
    }

}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but, this doesn't sound like good programming practice. What is it you want to do with this arraylist of classes?

Comment: @user All you need to do to load classes from a jar is to put the jar in your class path: `java -cp .;myjar.jar`, is there a reason why you feel you need to load the classes at runtime?

Comment: Are the files actually in a jar file? Your code looks like it is looking for them on disk...?

Comment: Houston we have a problem !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that what you want to do is to load a set of classes located in a JAR file or any other URL, then return a list containing those class objects.

My recommendations would be:

- Use the class `java.util.jar.JarFile` to read all entries in your jar.
- Iterate over the entries, and if a given entry belongs to a class (its name ends with ".class") then you load the class and add it to a list of loaded classes.

Somewhat like this:

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
for(JarEntry entry: Collections.list(jar.entries())){
   if(entry.getName().endsWith(".class")){
     String className = entry.getName().replace("/", ".").replace(".class","");
     foundClasses.add(loader.loadClass(className));
    }
}
```

For loading purposes you can use a `java.net.URLClassLoader` containing your jar file.

Somewhat like this

```
File jarFile = new File("./jedis.jar");
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()});
```

You will end up with all the loaded classes in the `foundClasses` list.

On the other hand, if you know exactly the classes that you want to load, then the URLClassLoader should suffice to solve the problem.

```
File jarFile = new File("./jedis.jar");
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()});
foundClasses.add(loader.loadClass("jedi.academy.ObiWan"));
foundClasses.add(loader.loadClass("jedi.academy.Luke"));
foundClasses.add(loader.loadClass("jedi.academy.Anakin"));
```

If you want that this secondary class loader be independent of the system class loader make sure to set the parent class loader to null when instantiating the URLClassLoader:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()}, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my query. I am wondering whether i can make these classes implement a common interface. Because i have to iterate over the list of classes and i want to store specific classes which implements a specific interface.

Comment: @user1282182 if this answered your question please mark it as such.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo Sry what is the type of foundClasses? Is it a Class or other thing?

Comment: @marzie I suppose the type of `foundClasses` must be `Collection<Class<?>>` or one of its subtypes.